# Periodic lockups showing kernel: [154858.820009] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* Hangcheck timer elapsed... render ring idle

Tags: 14.04, kernel

System is Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS with kernel 3.13.0-43-generic, I have noticed the lockups periodically since 09/13/2014. I can't remember what kernel version was in use then possibly kernel 3.13.0-35-generic or -36.

It has continued periodically through versions -39; -40 and now to -43. The last time this has happened was Dec 13 14:40:57 localhost kernel: [154858.820009] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* Hangcheck timer elapsed... render ring idle.

At times when it locks up I will have a cursor on a black screen and will have to press the power button to restart other times it will lockup whenever I'm in an application such as Firefox or Evolution. At that time I can usually CTRL>ALT-F1 log in and run `sudo reboot` to restart the system.

Some information that I've posted to Ubuntu Pastebin - Output of `lshw -C video` 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/9532767/ Output of `lspci` http://paste.ubuntu.com/9532795/

Another bit of information the may or may not help:

```
SourcePackage: linux
UpgradeStatus: No upgrade log present (probably fresh install)
dmi.bios.date: 02/13/2010
dmi.bios.vendor: Dell Inc.
dmi.bios.version: A03
dmi.board.name: 0C27VV
dmi.board.vendor: Dell Inc.
dmi.board.version: A01
dmi.chassis.asset.tag: LE0006476
dmi.chassis.type: 6
dmi.chassis.vendor: Dell Inc.
dmi.modalias: dmi:bvnDellInc.:bvrA03:bd02/13/2010:svnDellInc.:pnOptiPlex780:pvr:rvnDellInc.:rn0C27VV:rvrA01:cvnDellInc.:ct6:cvr:
dmi.product.name: OptiPlex 780
dmi.sys.vendor: Dell Inc.
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: This will help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743076/my-computer-hang-and-it-didnt-react-even-to-the-power-button/743079#743079