# My computer hang and it didn't react even to the power button!

Tags: crash

Help! I was surfing the web and listening to music on Ubuntu and suddenly it stopped reacting to anything. Mouse, power button, keyboard... It is still playing the same few second of music and I hear noisy work of HDD, and it reacts only to Fn+F7. What can I do?

Comment: You have to hold the power button down for *a few* seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/671591/occasional-lockups-drmi915-hangcheck-elapsed-error-hangcheck-timer-elapsed. I had the same
problem and those instructions saved me.

Especially if the freezing is sporadic/random and usually comes when you
are browsing with several tabs open and also streaming videos.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I was working with lot of open tabs and playing video, maybye this is the reason. My computer started to react to power button and I did a hard reset, it helped.

Comment: Although the link seems to have helped to resolved this person's problem, what would be nice is to futureproof this question so that if the link goes dead, the answer here is still useful. If you could edit it to reference a bug and/or include instructions to resolve it that would be awesome